# Find the limit of $\frac{2}{n^{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}[kx]$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Hey im first year math student I need to find the limit of $(a_n) =\frac{2}{n^{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}[kx]$

what I tried to do was $ \frac{2}{n^{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}[kx]=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2}{n^{2}}[kx]=\frac{2}{n^{2}}[kx]+\frac{2}{n^{2}}[kx]+...+\frac{2}{n^{2}}[kx] $

then I tried to use the Squeeze theorem but what i got the from one side

$ ?\leqslant\frac{1}{n}[1x]\leqslant\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2}{n^{2}}[kx] $

and from the other side:

$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2}{n^{2}}[kx]\leqslant\frac{1}{n}[nx]\leqslant x $

i assume the limit is x but how can i show it from the first side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{2}{n^{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{n} (kx-1) \leq a_n \leq \frac{2}{n^{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{n} kx,$$
or
$$\frac{2x}{n^{2}}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-\frac{2}{n} \leq a_n \leq \frac{2x}{n^{2}}\frac{n(n+1)}{2},$$
so the limit is equal to $x$, of course.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{2}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(kx) = \frac{2x}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k = \frac{2x}{n^2}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$